# How to make transparent Status Bar in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, reactjs-native

How to make transparent Status Bar in React Native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey the answer to your question is

```
      <StatusBar backgroundColor={'transparent'} translucent={true} />
```